# Imageview inside FrameLayout is stretching scaletype is centercrop

Tags: android, layout, imageview, rounded-corners

In my application I need `ImageView` with rounded corners, So I have set `ImageView` inside `framelayout`, When I set the `scaleType` `centerCrop`, the image set inside the `ImageView` is stretching in first loading and, again refreshing the page the image is not stretching and set with round corners.How can I avoid the first stretching.Thanks in advance
**Here is the XML code**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/imageframe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_80"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_80"
        android:background="@drawable/image_rounded"
        android:src="@drawable/dummypost1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/image_rounded"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_80"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_80"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: For rounded corner, you can take a look in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an `ImageView` with rounded corners, there is no need for wrapping like this.

you can use only `ImageView` in your layout and using `glide`, you can apply round corners using this method.

first in your gradle write,

> compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

for image with rounded corners,

```
public void loadImageWithCorners(String url, ImageView view) {
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .asBitmap()
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.color.gray)
            .error(R.color.gray)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(view) {
                @Override
                protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                    RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                            RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
                    circularBitmapDrawable.setCornerRadius(32.0f); // radius for corners
                    view.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                }
            });
}
```

call method :

```
loadImageWithCorners("your url","your imageview");
```